# How to vertically (and horizontally) center text of cells using tabularx?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tabularx

My question is very similar to this one: [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164256/table-column-auto-width-vertically-and-horizontally-centered)
but when I vary the example a little (as below), my cells are no longer vertically aligned

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Z}[0]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}%
\newcolumntype{s}[0]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.4\hsize}Z}%
\newcolumntype{n}[0]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.8\hsize}Z}%


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{7cm}{s|Z|s|n}
& really really really long\linebreak heading 1 & very very narrow column & \\
\toprule
row 1 & 2314 & 2134 & medium medium column \\ \hline
row 1 & 2314 & 2134 & medium medium  column
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Your column widths are inconsistent (and lead to underfull box warnings) you have 4 X columns so the total width has to be 4\hsize but you have 2.6\hsize:  tabularx can not do anything sensible with such a specification, anything it does is accidental:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beware that for resized `X` cells, the coefficients are like barycentric coordinates and their sum has to be equal to the columns number.

Also, I managed horizontal rules meet vertical rules, and set all rules (vertical as well as horizontal rules but one) to have the width of `\midrule`s, and I simplified your code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Z}[0]{>{\hsize=1.55\hsize}X}%
\newcolumntype{s}[0]{>{\hsize=.6\hsize}X}%
\newcolumntype{n}[0]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=1.25\hsize}X}%


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt} \setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{7cm}{s!{\vrule width\lightrulewidth}Z!{\vrule width\lightrulewidth}s!{\vrule width\lightrulewidth}n}
& really really really long\linebreak heading 1 & very very narrow column & \\
\toprule
row 1 & 2314 & 2134 & medium medium column \\ \midrule
row 1 & 2314 & 2134 & medium medium column
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Z}[0]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{s}[0]{>{\hsize=.4\hsize}Z}%
\newcolumntype{n}[0]{>{\hsize=.8\hsize}Z}%

\begin{document} 
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{7cm}{s|Z|s|n}
& really really really long heading 1 & very very narrow column & \tabularnewline
    \toprule
row 1 & 2314 & 2134 & medium medium column \\ 
    \hline
row 1 & 2314 & 2134 & medium medium  column
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This code gives:

[image]

As you see, the above code is quite simplified your code. Omit are all surplus `\centering` in your column type definition (in one place it is enough) and also is omit redefinition for `\arraybackslash` and `\hspace{0pt}` which seem to be one of causes of your problem (for second one see comment of David Carlisle).

Comment: see note about column widths on the question